# Minimum floor area covered by cubes or minimum cubes on the floor

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

There is a storeroom which has only 3 sides all touching each other perpendicularly (2 infinitely large walls and one infinitely large floor)
There are $N$ cubes of unit volume. To store cubes in the storeroom there are 2 rules -

1. Can be placed anywhere on the floor
2. Cube $A$ can be placed on Cube $B$ only if there are cubes on all four sides of $B$ unless the side is already blocked by a wall.

Find the minimum floor area covered for storing $N$ cubes.

Examples:

- if $N=3$: minimum floor area $= 3$
- if $N=4$: minimum floor area $= 3$, (as 4th cube can be placed on one in corner touching walls from 2 sides and 2 cubes on other sides)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
N = int(input())
n = int(np.real(np.roots([1,3,2,-6*N])[2]))
c = int(np.ceil(np.roots([1,1,-2*(N-int((n*(n+1)*(n+2))/6))])[1]))
print(int((n*(n+1))/2)+c)
```

This code in python will give the answer in constant time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't actually give the correct answer anyway since it does not try to stack up the leftover cubes.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with those equations?