# Minimizing floor space needed to store $N$ unit cubes, subject to two placement rules

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, algorithms, puzzle

> There is a store room which has only three sides all touching each other perpendicularly, the sides can be defined as: two infinitely large walls and one infinitely large floor.
>
> [image]
>
> There are $N$ cubes of unit volume. I need to store the cubes in the store room but there are two rules to be followed before storing:
>
> 1. A cube can be placed anywhere on the floor.
> 2. If a cube A is placed upon another cube B, then there should be a cube on all the four sides of the cube B unless the side is already blocked by a wall.
>
> I need to output the **minimum floor area covered for storing N cubes**.

Example

- $N = 3$ requires 3 unit square of floor area as all the cubes need to be placed on the floor.
- $N = 4$ requires 3 unit square of floor area. Let there be cubes A, B, C, D; cube A can be placed above the cube B, which is touching both the walls. Since cube B is touching both the walls it is blocked on 2 sides but open on 2 other sides, cubes C and D can be placed on the adjacent open sides of Cube B. Hence, Cube A can be placed on the cube B following the given rules.

I am trying to think it by intution but not coming up to a reasonable answer which could prove that my answer is correct.

Comment: Start by looking for how many you need on the bottom layer for a give number on the next layer. This has a reasonable pattern, and it is the basis for solving your problem.

Comment: I am trying to take different values of N then computing the possible answer but I am unable to see any pattern. Is there any 3D software to visualize this?

Comment: The possible size of each layer depends on the layer below it. In a 2-layer stack 1 on top needs 3 on the bottom, 2 needs 5, 3 needs 6. Then 4 on top needs 8, .. 6 needs 10. I did this with pencil and paper and the pattern for this was fairly easy to see. To get a 4 level stack you need 1 on top, so 3 next down, then 6 then 10 at the bottom. You are actually working it out in the opposite direction. Noting that 1 needs 3 needs 6 needs 10, if you have 17 blocks for example this is 10 or more and less than 20, so 3 levels. For 2 on top, need 5, then 9 totalling 16. 17 blocks - another on bottom

Comment: @coder_a "Is there any 3D software to visualize this?" You don't need such a thing. Use a 2D grid and put in the height in each square. You can increase the height of a square if and only if all four neighbouring squares have equal or higher height. The starting height of all squares is $0$, and the height of the wall is $\infty$.

Comment: Is this problem equivalent to the OEIS sequence [A123579](https://oeis.org/A123579) (The Kruskal-Macaulay function $M_3(n)$), or am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter thanks for your effort I think i can do this now after that explanation

Comment: @Vepir Yes it looks similar to it I have computed the values up to 20 and it looks the same as this function output. Can you explain more about that function? I am unable to understand the maple given in the link. I would like to generate that sequence using Computer Programming efficiently. Like if given N cubes do I have to generate all the numbers from 1 to N or  Can I formulate the sequence to get answer in O(1)

Comment: Exact same question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3794385/11619) also. Mind you, coder_a did a much better job asking. But, what's going on? Is this a homework assignment? Or is it from some programming contest? In the latter case we need the source identified so that we can ascertain that the due date of the contest is gone. We don't help people with on-going contests. Many of us are involved in organizing contests, and want to protect their integrity. Hence this policy.

Comment: Oh it was a Interview question you can find it here https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/800300/CodeNation-or-Online-Assessment-Hackerrank-or-17-August-2020-or-India/